# Lenovo OneKey recovery

Tags: partitioning, lenovo-laptop, system-restore

I've got a Lenovo G5045 laptop.

On default It has 2 visible partitions
1 Windows 8  (C:) 
2 lenovo (D:)
And invisible recovery partition, EFI partition.

The C drive is huge,  it was about 800 GB.
As my harddrive is 1 TB.
I shrinked the C Drive to use my contents.

Now the C drive is 120 GB in size and
I've got 2 new partitions for my storage

The question is:

If I restore my laptop with the default Recovery partition

1. Will it work?
2. Will it delete my 2 partitions (with all of my contents) and set the C drive to default size (above 800 GB )

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your recovery script pre-configured at Lenovo factory.
And I think it will destroy your partitions because you have changed the disk layout on your own.

An external backup would be nice before doing anything.